# How to convert library (uneditable .java/.class files) into editable .java files (standard classes in project)?

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, libraries

I am working with [Paho project for Android](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/). According to the instructions, while testing Android sample app, it is required to have both *AndroidService.jar* and *JavaClient.jar* included in the project. I import them in Android Studio and the app is working perfectly.

However, and that is my problem, I want to edit these precompiled java classes. But the problem is that, since they are imported as .jar files and that they are already compiled, they are uneditable in Android Studio.

I have the source code of the libraries I want to include into the project. Unfortunately, when I import them in the Android Studio, I get bunch of errors (which I do not usually get when I import .jar files).

The methods I tried up until now are to copy the source java classes into the project by creating new classes with same names and content. I also tried to import the whole source project as the module to my project. I get same errors. I also know about [this great fork](https://github.com/sandro-k/org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample) of the Paho project which lets you just to import whole project in Android Studio and it simply works. However, the *AndroidService* classes are still uneditable.

As I said, I have the needed source code. I can generate these .jar files without any problem from the source and then import them in the project. That method works. But to edit the java classes, then to compile them, then to import them in the Android Studio to test everything, and to do it every time when I change something, is a bit tiring. That is why I am asking for help.

Please, let me know if you know some approach which will let me to edit these two "**libraries**" while I am still in Android Studio, so I can test changes I make immediately.

*P.S. I have been Googling this so much and I believe that there is no ready solution for these online. However, If you find one, I will be really happy if you point to it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all I have no idea why you want to edit the Paho Android Service because it doesn't make to much sense. You are able to overwrite every class if necessary. Any way you would need to change the Android Service build from Maven to Gradle to include the source into you project.

To help you out I have just done that and pushed to the "withSouce" branch of my repository. https://github.com/sandro-k/org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample/tree/withSource

If you now want to replace the compile `org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2` with your sources as well you have to replace that with a local dependency as well.

Answer (score 1):

Jar files are really just compressed (zipped) versions of .class files (and a few other essential documents). Class files are compiled .java files. The only way to edit these jar files would be to unzip the jar with a program such as 7zip or WinRAR, then decompile the class to get the source code, edit it, and recompile. Decompiling is a very difficult, time consuming process, and would require external software. Your best bet would be to continue the process you've been using.

**Note:** If you still wish to decompile, you might want to check out [Cavaj](http://cavaj-java-decompiler.en.softonic.com/), a free java decompiler. But beware, it may not return the exact source code used in the jar.

**Sources:** Experience

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned in the question, I do not have to decompile. I already have the source code. The problem is that when I compile the source and add it to the project, it works. But when I import the source into the project directly, it does not work. I mean, I can edit the files, compile them and add them to the project, but that is tiring to do every time. I just want to add in form of Java classes so it is editable in Android studio directly. And I don't have best bet. I don't have process that I am using, I am searching for it. :/

Comment: My bad, i must have misunderstood the question. Sorry i was unable to help.